# How to fix "interface ICorProfilerInfo3 not found"

Tags: .net

I am trying to trace .NET application using Datadog .NET Tracer.
https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-dotnet/releases
The application and the tracer are installed on Windows 2008R2SP1x64 Std with .NET Framework 4.6.1.
It fails to trace with the following warning messages:

- .net tracer log:
  "Failed to attach profiler: interface ICorProfilerInfo3 not found."
- Windows Application Event log:
  "NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.8800 - Failed to CoCreate profiler."

The requirement for the .net tracer is .NET CLR 4.5 and above.
My understanding of .NET is that CLR is a component of the framework, hence CLR version is same as framework version.

I'm trying to understand why .NET runtime version (2.0.50727.8800 according to Windows event log) is older than the framework (4.6.1 according to the Windows control panel).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and installing the .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) and restarting the Datadog Agent solved the problem

- .net tracer log: [w3wp.exe] 3584: [info] Profiler attached.